# Indexing aggregate function in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have the following SQL query which I want to optimize using indexing.

```
select    ean,   count(nif)
from    produto   P,   fornece_sec   F where    P.ean   =   F.ean
group   by    P.ean
having    count(nif)   >   1
```

Makes sense to use an index for nif?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Please learn how to use modern explicit `JOIN` syntax rather than the ancient and outdated implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: I got this question as part of an assignment. The teacher made that query,it is so badly written that I can't even run it on my database, and asked to write indexes. And my doubt is should I index nif, and if yes, what type of index? Hash or b-tree? Clustered or Unclustered? Note that only one of nine possible values satisfies the query.

Answer (score 0):

First, learn how to write queries correctly using explicit `join` syntax:

```
select P.ean, count(nif)
from produto P join
     fornece_sec F 
     on P.ean = F.ean
group by P.ean
having count(nif) > 1;
```

Then -- assuming that all `ean`s in `fornece_sec` are also in `produto` -- you don't need the `join`, because you are aggregating by the `join` key.  So, you can simplify this to:

```
select F.ean, count(F.nif)
from fornece_sec F 
group by F.ean
having count(F.nif) > 1;
```

For this version of the query, you can use a covering index:  `fornece_sec(ean, nif)`.